# Using "Request Access" API of Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to request access for a project deployed in azure devops using my application through Azure devops rest api.

I came across the API "Request access" (https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/requestaccess?api-version=5.1-preview.1)

the document for the above URL: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/request%20access/request%20access?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1.

In the document of the above URL, its not mentioned about what has to be given as payload to access the API. The body content is just mentioned as String.

Can someone please help me, by providing more insight in using the above mentioned Rest API.

Thanks in advance

I tried googling for the same, But couldn't get related information anywhere.

Comment: Hi, how are problems going? Could you get clearly body from the way I provide? Feel free to share your progress:-)

Answer (score 1):

First, apologize for this doc missing so that let you not too clear about it.You can get the body of this API from the F12 console.

First, try to access one org that you do not have permission to access. And then, you will see one button which names **Request Access**.

[image]

Before click it, please press F12 first so that you can monitor its API process and the request body.

And then, click this **Request Access** button, and input the content for request reason:
[image]

And then, you will see the api and its request body in console:

[image]

Here is the **request body**:

[image]

The content of the request body is the message you will send to the administrator. For me, I wrote `request for accessing`. So the request body is

```
"request for accessing"
```

You can also get the exactly content type from the console. In this API, it's **application/json**

Hope this can give you help.

As Hugh said, the ticket you raised in DC has been taken by our product group. They are investigating for this.

Answer (score 0):

You asked the same issue in the Developer Community forum, and this issue has been fed back to the product team to add the reference to the request body.

Once the product team accepts this case, they will give a reply as soon as possible, and we will keep you informed of the latest progress. Please wait patiently.

If you need it urgently,you can vote the original [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/659555/bad-request-while-requesting-access-using-azure-gr.html),everyone else can also add their vote directly,because voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. I have voted for your case :).Hoping your issue will be solved as soon as possible.